# How to get all values from a key of dictionaries which are in a list which is in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a Dictionary which looks like this:

```
response = {
     'name': "ExampleName",
     'tier': 'Master',
     'queue': 'RANKED_SOLO_5x5',
     'entries': [
          {
         'playerOrTeamId': '35417098',
         'playerOrTeamName': 'ExamplePlayerName',
         'wins': 205,
         'losses': 185
         },
         {
         'playerOrTeamId': '22877699',
         'playerOrTeamName': 'ExamplePlayerName2',
         'division': 'I',
         'leaguePoints': 80,
         'wins': 300,
         'losses': 272
          }
      ]
}
```

And so on. Now I want to `print` all the `playerOrTeamId's`
I already tried:

```
print(response['entries']['playerOrTeamId'])
```

which gives me this Error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

but if I try for example this:

```
print(response['entries'][0]['playerOrTeamId'])
```

it only gives me the `playerOrTeamId` of the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to retrieve all the ids from the response.

```
all_ids = [entry["playerOrTeamId"] for entry in response["entries"]]
```

This is fancy Python shorthand for looping through the responses and creating a list of the just the ids.

Comment: Is there also a way to get all ids and names in a dict like this: `name_id_dict={'name': 'id'}`?

Comment: What do you mean by `get`? You can just access the dictionary to retrieve the `id`s using the `name`. If you want to iterate over the `names` you'll have to make the dictionary iterable by using `.items()`. e.g. `for key, value in name_id_dict.items(): # Do stuff`

Comment: [Dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) is also possible if that's what you're talking about